# Using angular, Is it possible somehow to display a value with a filter directly to html code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Usualy, you are using filter directly in your html code like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:{ category : 'car' }">
```

But in my case I need to use filter to display a value. Something like this :

```
<p> {{products.length | filter:{category : 'car'} }} Car Product(s) found.</p>
```

In order to get as output :

`8 Car Product(s) found.` (example)

**NOTE :**

I know how to do it using javascript but this is not what I'm looking for. I want to know if it's possible to do it directly in my html code.

Comment: Yes,You can use it inside the {{}} notation.

Comment: @MarcusH Can you give me an example ? Please thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
<div ng-repeat="product in filter = ( products | filter:{ category : 'car' })">
```

And to display the amount just :

```
{{filter.lentgh}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filters inside the {{}} notation almost anywhere in the html document.

Call it the same way as always: `{{scope_value | YourFilter}}`

Here's an example of a filter used directly in the {{}} notation:

```
<body ng-app="inputExample">
  <script>
   angular.module('inputExample', [])
     .controller('InputController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.val = 0;
     }]).filter('YesNo', function () {
    return function (num) {
        return num === 0 ? 'Zero' : 'Not Zero';
    };
});
</script>
<div ng-controller="InputController">

    <label>
       Add number or zero
       <input type="number" ng-model="val">
    </label>
   <label> {{val | YesNo}} </label>

</div>
</body>
```

[Here's](https://plnkr.co/edit/gh8MprKH2E1I2exEaP42?p=preview) a plunker

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

{{ (products | filter:{category : 'car'}).length }} Car Product(s) found.

Comment: Cleanest answer ;)

Comment: You are iterating products outside the ng-repeat, certainly not the cleanest answer.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas In angular js official site there is no any specification regarding filter use only in ng-repeat.

Comment: It's basic to no iterating an array twice, if you don't need to, you don't need the angular official site.

Comment: If he has a million objects in this array your code will slow down the website.

Comment: Yes you are right @ItsikMauyhas if he has millions of object then it may be slow but ng-repeat prints n times input fields.